# In Java is there a static version of 'this'

Tags: java

I know this is quite minor, but at the top of every class I end up copying and pasting and then changing the following line of code.

```
private static final String TAG = MyClass.class.getName();
```

What I would like to do is not to have to modify the MyClass bit every time I copy.

i.e. I would like to write this.

```
private static final String TAG = this.class.getName();
```

but clearly there is no this at this point. I know its minor, but I generally learn something from SO answers, and indeed learnt some good stuff just searching to see if there was an answer already.

Comment: It is also error prone if you make a typo for MyClass.class with a valid classname. Happened to me more than once ;-)

Comment: Or if you are careless about cut-n-paste "reuse".

Comment: `new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingClass()`, or something, as mentioned on a duplicate question. (Does cost extra.)

Comment: Like it, better than throwing and catching exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an **Eclipse template**, called `tag`, for example:

```
private static final String TAG = ${enclosing_type}.class.getName();
```

Then, type `tag` followed by `Ctrl+Space` and it will insert this statement.

I use this method to declare loggers in my classes.

Alternatively, query the stack trace of the current Thread:

```
private static final String TAG = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
```

Comment: getStackTrace()[1] or getStackTrace()[0] as mentioned later?

Comment: Should be getStackTrace()[1] on a Thread. The other answer is different because it creates a new RuntimeException.

Answer (score 3):

An ugly hack but, this will give you the current class name:

private static String tag = new RuntimeException().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to avoid this. You have to specify the class token for each class explicitly. Reflection could possibly provide some general way to deal with this, but it would be so much more ugly that it is not worth thinking about it :-)

Comment: Not possible with Reflection. You have got to start with a `Class` somewhere and let's that be the first problem already.

Answer (score 1):

`this` stands for instance specific stuffs. For Class level stuffs use class name or just call them explicitly, if you are calling from within the class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know how I've wished for something like that (`this.class`), but sadly, no.

Answer (score 1):

User dogbane suggested querying the stack trace of the current `Thread`.
One might move out that code into a class named `ClassInfo`:

```
package util;

public class ClassInfo {
    private ClassInfo() {}
        static public String className() {
            return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
    }
}
```

Then, from a static context, we can get the class name by referring to `ClassInfo.className()` or simply `className()` if we use a static import.

Example:

```
import static util.ClassInfo.className;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( className() );
        Inner.print();
    }

    private static class Inner {
        static void print() {
            System.out.println( className() );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MyClass
MyClass$Inner
```